# Jquery radio buttons logic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm missing a piece of logic somewhere.  I want to know if the radio button is true or false.

The console shows;

```
adjunct_prof
<input type=​"radio" name=​"adjunct_prof" id=​"adjunct_prof" value=​"False" checked=​"checked">​ 
<input type=​"radio" name=​"adjunct_prof" id=​"adjunct_prof" value=​"True">​
```

The HTML is;

```
<div id="ProfessorDiv" class="span4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
        Are you an adjunct professor?&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="adjunct_prof" id="adjunct_prof" value="False" 
        <cfif request.adjunct_prof EQ "False">  checked="checked"</cfif> /> No 
        <input type="radio" name="adjunct_prof" id="adjunct_prof" value="True" 
        <cfif request.adjunct_prof EQ "True"> checked="checked"</cfif>  /> Yes 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4" id="ProfSpecsDiv">
        <cfinclude template="adjunct_prof.cfm">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script is;

```
$("input:radio[name=adjunct_prof]").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value);
    if (value = 'True') {
        $('#ProfSpecsDiv').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#ProfSpecsDiv').hide();      
    }
});
```

The alert shows either True or False depending on the status of the buttons.  But when I click on "Yes" the div is displayed. When I click on "No" nothing happens.  The div is still displayed.  And the dev tool shows that the "show" code is executed every time.  I have tried True and 'True' the default if (value) {.

Comment: You used a single = in your if statement ;)

Comment: You need comparison === and not assignment =.

Comment: Would it not be easier to use 1 and 0, then it would evaluate as boolean directly, then you can just test as `if(active)`?

Answer (score 4):

`if (value = 'True')`

You have used a single = instead of == which will cause value to always be assigned 'True' and `#ProfSpecsDiv` to always be shown.

Comment: I actually changed it just for grins even though I know better.  But, changing it back to == works now.  Shouldn't if (value) have worked?

Comment: No, `if(value)` is not the same thing; you are doing a string comparison, not a boolean one. It will check to see if `value` has something stored in it. This will cause `#ProfSpecsDiv` to be shown regardless of whether it is set to 'True' or 'False'.

Answer (score 2):

Dont's set the same id more than once. Each button is an element. You can use class instead.

```
<input type=​"radio" name=​"adjunct_prof" class=​"adjunct_prof adjunct_prof_yes" value=​"False" checked> <!-- Simply checked is valid html5 -->​ 
<input type=​"radio" name=​"adjunct_prof" class=​"adjunct_prof adjunct_prof_no" value=​"True">​
```

You only need to check the value of one of the boxes since it's bool anyway. Have you considered using a checkbox?

```
$(".adjunct_prof").on('change', function(){
    if($('.adjunct_prof_yes').prop('checked')) {
        $('#ProfSpecsDiv').show();
    } else {
        $('#ProfSpecsDiv').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, but my specs call for a "Yes/No" radio.